# how to save value in database for check box

Tags: database

Depending on some requirements a user can select 5-10 checkboxes in my rails app. What would be the best way to save the check box values in database. I have two idea so far. The concept here is that in my database I want to save client_id and 5-10 products id in the database.

I can do that in two ways, 1) I can have 10 column for 10 products and another column for client_id and then if client select 7 products then client id and 7 products id will be saved and other 3 column will be blank in one row.

or 2) in second case we can use two column client_id and product_id and then we can use seven row like below to save the above 7 products.

```
client1_id    product1_id
client1_id    product2_id
.
.
.client2_id   product1_id
```

What should be the good approach to save this in database?

Comment: According to my opinion you should use enum type field and insert their values

Comment: Could you please show a sample code? I don't understand you.

Comment: enum will be the same. because an enum can hold only one of a choice set at a time. I go for storing a json like string that stores product types that have been checked. Or more simply, an array string that contains all the products that a client checked.

Comment: @sivatumma If he/she wants to insert multiple then it would be best to insert by comma seprated.

Comment: Yes, csv would be good too.

Comment: Storing CSV values is cosidered a bad approach, i think point#2 is best way of storing as store seperate record per product selected by user in purchase table.

Comment: I want to save in database not in csv or any other file